# I am i am using setInterval to record time. and i clear the interval Using clearInterval but not working

Tags: youtube-api, clearinterval

I am using Youtube api, here i need to record the user watch time, so i use setInterval function to reord the time. when video play record function runs after every 500 ms sec using setInterval. and when video pause i clear that id (i.e return by sertInterval) using clearInterval, but is not working. record function still running. and in the meanwhile i start video again at that point the record function run more faster than given interval(500). calling 4-6 time in 1 sec.Is am i doing anything wrong . please suggest me. here below is my code:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event){
    if(event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING || event.data === YT.PlayerState.UNSTARTED){
        if(!timeSpent.length){
            for(var i=0, l=parseInt(player.getDuration()); i<l; i++) 
            timeSpent.push(false);
        }
        timer = setInterval(recordTime, 500);

    }else if(event.data === YT.PlayerState.PAUSED){ // paused or move forward
        if(parseInt(event.target.getCurrentTime()) == parseInt(lastSeenPoint)){ // paused
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = 0;
        }else if(event.target.getCurrentTime() > lastSeenPoint || 
            event.target.getCurrentTime() < lastSeenPoint){ // move forward
            seekcount = seekcount+1;
        }

    }else if(event.data === YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }else if(event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED){ // video completed           
        lastSeenPoint = 0;
        setVideoTrackData();
        isVideoEnd = true;
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}


function recordTime(){
    var recordExist = false;    
    lastSeenPoint = player.getCurrentTime();   
    if(!isVideoEnd){
        setVideoTrackData();
    }
    timeSpent[ parseInt(player.getCurrentTime()) ] = true;
    calculateActualTime();
    var currentInterActivity = _.filter(interactivity, function(item){return item.tick == parseInt(player.getCurrentTime()) });
    console.log("interactivitytaken : "+isInteractivityTaken);
    if(currentInterActivity.length && currentInterActivity[0].tick==parseInt(player.getCurrentTime()) && isInteractivityTaken == false){
        player.pauseVideo();
        isInteractivityTaken = true;
        showInteractivityModal(currentInterActivity);
    }else{      
        isInteractivityTaken = false;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf4Vg.png)

Comment: My guess is `timer` is being initialized more than once.

Comment: So cancel it before you start it again. `if(timer) { clearTimeout(timer); } timer = ...`